# Licence in redhat

Tags: linux, licensing, redhat

I just installed Redhat 5.
As I read in some forums, without an installation key Redhat does not install some tools.
Which command shows whether the license key is updated or not?

Comment: I would suggest using CentOS or Scientific Linux if you don't wish to purchase a copy of RHEL.

Comment: @Süleyman Şengül Welcome to our community, but if I may make a couple of suggestions? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq. There you will see that questions here are meant to be on programming topics. Linux questions about non-programming installation topics are not meant for here. I would also encourage you to work a little more on your grammar and run a spell check. Thank you.

Comment: Ok Sintia, I will take into consideration your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking here: /etc/sysconfig/rhn/install-num

This should tell you the license key that you have entered.

If you're wondering what you're missing out on if you don't have a valid license key, check out [What access and functionality do I lose when the support contract expires for a Red Hat Enterprise Linux product?](https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-1617) on the RedHat support site.

From the site:

> > When you purchase an entitlement for Red Hat Enterprise Linux you are purchasing access to support resources and access to Red Hat
> >     Network (RHN) resources, which includes all errata and updates.
> >     Without and active entitlement you will not receive any support or any
> >     updates.   You will still be able to log on to RHN with your account
> >     login, but will not have any active channel entitlements to receive
> >     any errata updates. The up2date command will not work because there is
> >     no channel to associate your system to.   If you log in to
> >     https://www.redhat.com/apps/support/ you can see your active
> >     entitlements and all support resources that comes with those
> >     entitlements.   You can also log on to RHN and view your RHN
> >     entitlements by clicking on the "Channels" tab at the top, then on
> >     "Channel Entitlements" link on the left hand side. You will see your
> >     current channel entitlement(s).

If you're looking for a free alternative to RedHat, try out CentOS or Fedora.